# How to apply updates using Domain Service Class?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services, ria

I'm able to successfully use the "Get" operations and joining multiple tables by creating concrete classes while using the domain service class. IE:

```
public IQueryable<**custom data object type**> GetInvoice
{
      return from i in this.ObjectContext.tablename
             join o in this.ObjectContext.tablename
             select new **custom data object type**
             {
                  Field1 = i.Field1
                  Field2 = i.Field2
                  Field3 = new **custom data object type**
                           {
                                 Field1 = o.Field1
                                 ... = ...
                           }
             }
}
```

This Get Operation was successful. I need to know, How Can apply updates from a "Custom data object type" to those individual entities inside the domain service class?

Answer (score 1):

First off you will need an update method in your DomainService:

```
public void UpdateObject(T currentObj)
{
    this.ObjectContext.Ts.AttachAsModified(currentObj, this.ChangeSet.GetOriginal(currentObj));
}
```

Secondly you will need to call SubmitChanges on your DomainContext class.

Comment: Yes, I understand that this method is generated for you when creating the domain service class. But in this case the "currentObj" would be a combination of multiple entities.

Comment: @jammer you just need to provide an update method for each type of Entity that you have and the DomainContext's EntityContainer will figure out all the related objects that need to be updated and call the corresponding update method for them.